# Having trouble creating a script for google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm creating a stat sheet for my D&D campaign and would like to keep track of how much damage each character deals. I was hoping to create a macro that's attached to a button that adds the value of one cell to the current value of another cell.

Example: The current value of cell B4 is 12. I input 23 into cell H4 and press the button. Cell B4 is now 35 and the value of cell H4 is reset to 0.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: You might be able to use onSelectionChange(e) to track which cells are being clicked in order to capture the last two cells at the same time.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. As questions on this site should be specific and they should be about programming please provide more details. What stops you to create the macro? Do you already tried something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome blooturtleduck. This script would do exactly what you've asked for:

```
function myFunction() {
  currentValue = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(4,2).getValue();  //get value from B4 (B = column 2)
  newValue = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(4,8).getValue();  //get value from H4 (H = column 8)
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(4,2).setValue(currentValue+newValue); //set B4 to the sum of those two values
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(4,8).clear(); //Clear H4
}

function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('myFunction', 'myFunction')
      .addToUi();
}
```

The first function changes the cell values.
The second function adds a custom menu so you can call the function from the Google Sheets menu.

If you'd prefer to click a button image in the spreadsheet, check out instructions here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus

I recommend having a read of best practices for Google Apps Script:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices

For example, rather than calling individual getValue operations for each cell, it is usually much faster to call one getValues for a whole sheet, do all of the processing you want, and then one setValues at the end (because each call from AppsScript to Sheets takes time).

Comment: Gah! I was so close with what I was trying yesterday! Thank you so much I appreciate you